# Var of added gaussian noise

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have basically this:

```
I = im2double(imread('lena.png'));

% Add gaussian noise
J = imnoise(I,'gaussian',0,0.05);
```

Now having both undegraded image `I` and noised image `J` how can I estimate that the variance used for gaussian noise was `0.05`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain the noise waveform via subtraction.  You can obtain the sample variance with `var()`.

Of course, the sample variance is only an estimate for the true variance.

Answer (score 2):

Subtract J from I, square each difference, and take the average.  Since you know the mean (zero) you can use the number of pixels as the denominator in your average.